# Transform JSON: select one row from array of json objects

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't get a specific row from this JSON array.
So I want to get the object where filed 'type' is equal to 'No-Data'

Are there exist any functions in SQL to take the row or some expressions?

```
 "metadata": { "value": "JABC" },
 "force": false
 "users": [
     { "id": "111", "comment": "aaa", type: "Data" },
     { "id": "222", "comment": "bbb" , type:"No-Data"},
     { "id": "333", "comment": "ccc", type:"Data" }
 ]
```

Comment: You json demo is not correct formed. see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b852d5cffc28848bf053166d812f9fa5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$.users[*] ? (@.type == "No-Data")')
from the_table
```

This assumes that the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not you have to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d15d771826b8b0821c71226755a5e1cd)

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name 
also, can I extract only id from this json?

Comment: Just use `->> 'id'` on the result. But your question was "*to get the object*" which is what I answered.

Comment: yeah, thank you a lot, I have figured out only now